# Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined react-native-app-auth

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, appauth

I have an error when I try the example code of this package. I watched several topics or the Github issue but no solution seems to work

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/react-native-app-auth/tree/master/Example/AndroidExample

TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can share with us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved :

Just need to run with `react-native run-android` instead of `react native start`

Comment: This is not a right solution. When I run with 'run-android' command, I got the same error.